# Prevent Docusign signer from changing name

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to prevent a signer from changing their name at signing after the envelope has been sent out?

Basically, I want the name of the user to stay the same throughout the process. I'm using the API to create the envelope, so maybe there's something in the API call?

Comment: Which Field types are you using? Can you share the JSON for your createEnvelope request.

Comment: looks like it's an Admin Setting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you can limit it in the Admin Settings

- Signing Settings
- [Signature Adoption Configuration](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/signature-adopt-config.htm)
- Lock Recipient Name

[image: Lock Recipient Name]